# Are the spark ml libraries suitable for classifying instances one by one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, classification, apache-spark-mllib

The Spark `ml` library proudly presents it's capability of [model selection](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/ml-guide.html#example-model-selection-via-cross-validation). I thought it fits my use case:

1. *In bigdata world:* Train on many many labeled data points, do clever model selection by tuning parameters etc. and save the best model to disk.
2. *Outside bigdata world:* Load the model from disk and run a webservice (or something) that uses that model to label unlabelled datapoints.

Looking at the somewhat older `mllib` [library](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.ClassificationModel). It seems to understand my use case, there's a function `predict(testData: Vector): Double` that doesn't seem to require a spark context to be running.

But then it turns out that the models from the more recent (and recommended) `ml` [library](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayesModel) has no `transform()` function that transforms one single label. All functions requires an `RDD` of something which requires a spark context. And I don't want my web server to have to be run from a spark context.

What must I know about spark and machine learning? Is the functionality I want simply not implemented yet or is it infeasible to use spark's machine library like this to classify datapoints one by one.